# Reorganizing data by date and count in r

Tags: r, reorganize

I have data that looks like the following:

```
> head(z, 10)
         date year      long      lat
1  01/18/2017 2017 -92.48474 29.76465
2  01/22/2017 2017 -93.11126 29.83961
3  12/28/2013 2013 -91.30789 29.41938
4  01/08/2014 2014 -93.09949 29.80632
5  01/03/2014 2014 -90.55703 29.44535
6  12/31/2013 2013 -90.39836 29.57244
7             2013 -93.56322 30.30028
8  11/24/2013 2013 -93.45932 29.78530
9  11/19/1994 1994 -93.58333 29.75000
10 11/15/2013 2013 -89.16171 29.45222
```

There are multiple entries on some days, whereas some entries do not have a date. Those without a date I'm not interested in. What I want to know is how many records there are for each date and to insert missing days, when none records were created, so there is a record for each day of the year for each year whether data was recorded or not, such as:

```
> head(z2)
     m_d y_2017 y_2016 y_2015 y_2014 y_2013
1 01-02     16     15      0     29      9
2 01-03      0     38     25     10      3
3 01-04     13     20     14      5      7
4 01-05     19      0      3      0     16
5 01-06     34     25     29     33     24
6 01-07      3     10      5     34      7
```

Using the aggregate function I have been able to figure out how many records there were for each day.

```
> #create a value for the aggregate function to sum
z$count<-rep(1, length(z$year))
m<-aggregate(count ~ date, data = z, sum)
> head(m)
            date count
1                  308
2     01/01/1980     1
3     01/01/1985     1
4     01/01/1995     1
5     01/01/1996     2
6     01/01/1997     1
```

I have no idea how to go from this table, which is the information I need, into the format that I want in a resourceful manner. I could manually subset by year and merge the data from each year with a complete set of months/days for that year, then create a new `df` using all the different years, but this seems overly cumbersome and repetitive since I have data going back to 1980. Anyone know of an efficient way of reorganizing this data into the above format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create a reference dataframe with all dates from 1980 to present:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
all_dates <- seq(from = as.Date("1980-01-01"), to = as.Date("2018-05-02"), by = 'days'))
ref_dates = data.frame(date = all_dates)

df <- merge(df, ref_dates, all.y = TRUE)
df$date <- substring(df$date, 6,10)  # remove year from date column

df_table <- table(df$date, df$year) # cross tab
final_df <- as.data.frame.matrix(df_table) # convert into dataframe if you like
```

Comment: This worked great!  Thanks for the clear annotation too!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I would use `separate()` from `tidyr` package to split the 'date' column into 'm_d' and 'year'. And then, using `gather()` from the same package to change this long table to be wider. After this step, you could get a data frame with colnames 'm_d', 'y_2017', 'y_2016'...... You can do `sum(length())` later for counts.

Answer (score 0):

Using Base R:

```
d=transform(aggregate(long~date+year,dat,length),date=format(strptime(date,"%m/%d/%Y"),"%m-%d"),count=long,long=NULL)
> as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(count~date+year,d))
      1994 2013 2014 2017
01-03    0    0    1    0
01-08    0    0    1    0
01-18    0    0    0    1
01-22    0    0    0    1
11-15    0    1    0    0
11-19    1    0    0    0
11-24    0    1    0    0
12-28    0    1    0    0
12-31    0    1    0    0
```